# Find and replace second occurence of beginning of line using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, csv, sed

Let's say I have a CSV file formatted like so:

```
1,Mark
1,Smith
2,Janet
2,Smith
```

And I need to make it like this:

```
1,Mark Smith
2,Janet Smith
```

I will need to replace every occurrence of any given line opener after the first, then concatenate any line without an opener into the last line that did. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

To append next line to pattern space and remove newline character followed by a digit:

```
sed 'N;s/\n[0-9]//;s/,/ /2g' file
```

In case there could be only one or more than two occurrences:

```
sed ':a;N;s/^\([0-9][0-9]*\)\(.*\) *\n\1,/\1\2 /;ta;P;D;' file
```

Comment: You might want to remove the second or more comma(s) and replace by space(s)

Answer (score 0):

With awk is easier, and will work good no matter how many occurences you might have or no matter if the data are sorted or not:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{!a[$1]?a[$1]=$0:a[$1]=a[$1] " " $2}END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file1
```

Comment: can anyone know what will be the Regex for this example in notepad++?